# GIT pushing a new project for the first time

Tags: git, version-control, repository, git-push

I have a project on my local machine I've been working on alone, that I'd like to push to a remote server (running ubuntu & gitosis)

On the remote server I did

```
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/stefan/.git/
```

Locally `git status` says

```
git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .DS_Store
#   .travis.yml
#   license.txt
#   nbproject/
#   bla/.DS_Store
#   bla/cache/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I have also done

```
git remote add origin dev@123.456.xx.xxx:psdemo.git
```

Now: when I try to push, the following happens

```
git push origin master
fatal: 'psdemo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It makes sense in a way since I just have an empty git repo.

How can I push my files to this remote server? I guess what I need is cloning from my local machine to the remote machine, somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string

> ```
> dev@123.456.xx.xxx:psdemo.git
> ```

should be a valid ssh path. As far as I see in the previous line:

> ```
> git init
> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/stefan/.git/
> ```

You created a repository in /home/stefan/ so I would expect something like:

```
stefan@123.456.xx.xxx:~
```

But probably it isn't what you want. You should create a folder `psdemo.git` in your home in the remote server. For this, do a

```
git init --bare ~/psdemo.git
```

In that and then add the remote with:

```
 stefan@123.456.xx.xxx:~/psdemo.git
```

Then you should be able to push!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot push an empty project to the upstream. You have to add some files via `git add` and them commit them locally using `git commit`. Only after that you can push your changes into the upstream.

Ensure the remote repository can accept commits.

Answer (score 1):

The path to your remote repository may be incomplete. Instead of `psdemo.git`, try something like `/home/stefan/.git/` and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `Initialized empty Git repository in /home/stefan/.git/` part, your remote repo is not psdemo.git, but rather /home/stefan (or maybe /home/stefan/.git would work).

BTW: you usually use bare repositories on remotes (`git init --bare`), so that they don't have a working copy there.

Answer (score 1):

By this:

> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/stefan/.git/

it looks like you initialized your home directory on the remote server as a repository.

But this:

> git remote add origin dev@123.456.xx.xxx:psdemo.git

is adding your `${HOME}/psdemo.git` as the remote URL. This does not match, which is why you get the error.

Try `git init /home/stefan/psdemo.git` on the remote.